# fast way to filter large pandas DataFrame by different grouped columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to filter a huge python pandas dataframe. There are four columns in the table.

```py
FLAT_DF.head() 
---

chr     loc     cell                    reads
1       6458    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6459    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6460    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6461    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        3
1       6462    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6463    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6464    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6465    TCTTTCCTCACGGTTA        1
1       6914    GGGCACTTCGGAAATA        1
1       6914    ACGATGTTCAGTTAGC        1
1       6914    CGACTTCGTTGTACAC        1
1       6914    AACTGGTCACGCTTTC        1
1       6914    TGTTCCGTCGTTTAGG        1
1       6914    GACTGCGGTGTTTGGT        2
1       6914    AGCTCCTTCCACGACG        1
```

I try to filter the dataframe by a set of complicate rules.

```py
FILTERED_DF = FLAT_DF[
    # filter cell with enough coverage
    (FLAT_DF.groupby('cell').reads.transform(lambda x: x.sum()) > 10000) &
    # filter cell has informative site
    (FLAT_DF.groupby('cell').reads.transform(lambda x: (x > 5).sum()) > 10) &
    # filter site has informative cell
    (FLAT_DF.groupby(['chm', 'loc']).reads.transform(lambda x: (x > 1).sum()) > 10)
    ].reset_index()
```

The code above works fine on sample data, but take a very long time to finish when filtering the whole table. 
Is there a better way to achieve it? Can I use `np.where()` instead?

Comment: `(FLAT_DF.groupby('cell').reads.transform(lambda x: x.count()) > 1000)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would construct it this way using [**`numpy.bincount`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.cell.values)
g, t = pd.factorize(list(zip(df.chr.values.tolist(), df['loc'].values.tolist())))

r = df.reads.values

cond1 = (np.bincount(f, r) > 10000)[f]
cond2 = (np.bincount(f, r > 5) > 10)[f]
cond3 = (np.bincount(g, r > 1) > 10)[g]
cond4 = (np.bincount(f) > 1000)[f]

df[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4]
```

---

**Explanation**

- `pd.factorize` returns an integer factorization of an array of hashable things.  In the case of `f, u` we are factorizing the `'cell'` column.  Where `u` are the unique cell values (which we don't need here)
- `np.bincount` counts the number of times a "bin" is referenced and would tell us how many times each unique cell showed up in the `'cell'` column **if** we had just passed the `f` argument.  But we didn't, we also passed `r` which is the `weights` argument.  Instead of incrementing by one every time a "bin" from `f` is encountered, we increment by the corresponding value in `r`.  This acts as a `groupby` and `sum`.  By subsequently slicing that result with `f`, we effectively get a `groupby`, `transform`, `sum`.  This will be far quicker than the `transform` you were doing.
- This same logic follows for the other conditions and factorization.

Comment: I write an benchmark code snippets, and I notice that your method is ~300 times faster. Thank you very much.

Comment: I also want to filter group count. `(FLAT_DF.groupby('cell').reads.transform(lambda x: x.count()) > 1000)`. How to do that in `np.bincount`?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem.